# aspnet_client folder within IIS website

Tags: iis-6

I want to know how to permanently remove the aspnet_client folder under some of our websites in IIS.

Our application does not require it, and scripts against these folders fail due to the folder permissions on this folder.

Answer (score 3):

Even the .NET 4 install continues to add this folder. There doesn't seem to be a permanent way to delete the folder, outside of deleting it after registering .NET with IIS, or after installing a new version of the .NET Framework.

Some people say they throw a read-only attribute on the directory, but ... that still keeps the directory hanging about.

See my answer to a similar question, [Prevent aspnet_client folder being added to .NET sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031939/prevent-aspnet-client-folder-being-added-to-net-sites/6061229#6061229)

To reiterate that answer:

Check out the MSDN documentation on the [ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). There's an e and ea command line switch you should be able to use to clean it up after the fact.

> You can use Aspnet_regiis.exe to install and remove system client-side script, such as script for client-side validation. Use the -c option to install client script for the version of ASP.NET that is associated with the tool. (Script is installed in the Aspnet_client subdirectory of each IIS site directory.) To remove the client-side script for just the ASP.NET version that is associated with the tool, use the -e option. **To remove the client-side script for all installed versions of ASP.NET, use the -ea option.**

(Emphasis added.)

Comment: The folder seems to appear after windows updates has been installed, so on our web servers I've added a scheduled task which runs `aspnet_regiis.exe -ea` when WindowsUpdateClient logs EventID 19. Hopefully this will be a good workaround until someone finds a permanent fix.