# Prevent aspnet_client folder being added to .NET sites

Tags: asp.net

Yes, other questions here dive into the why. I know why the folder is added.
But I haven't seen this question answered:

How do I make sure the aspnet_client is never added to my .net sites, EVER?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the MSDN documentation on the [ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). There's an e and ea command line switch you should be able to use to clean it up after the fact.

> You can use Aspnet_regiis.exe to install and remove system client-side script, such as script for client-side validation. Use the -c option to install client script for the version of ASP.NET that is associated with the tool. (Script is installed in the Aspnet_client subdirectory of each IIS site directory.) To remove the client-side script for just the ASP.NET version that is associated with the tool, use the -e option. **To remove the client-side script for all installed versions of ASP.NET, use the -ea option.**

(Emphasis added.)

Unfortunately, even the .NET 4 installer adds this directory, so clean-up will continue to be required.

Comment: The folder seems to appear after windows updates has been installed, so on our web servers I've added a scheduled task which runs `aspnet_regiis.exe -ea` when WindowsUpdateClient logs EventID 19. Hopefully this will be a good workaround until someone finds a permanent fix.

Comment: Good idea, @Sense545! It's logged to the **System** log to save others wondering.

Comment: I found that the folder is also created when installing a new .NET Framework version, which does not log Event 19. I have now set the scheduled task to run on startup as well.